# Strange namespacing in .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

in Visual Studio 2017 I have a solution with aspnet core project and about 10 net core libraries referenced to each other.

One of the libraries is xUnit test project. It referenced to another project it should use as aim for testing.

For example I have:

```
Project: MyProject.Domain
Test Project: MyProject.Domain.Tests
```

MyProject.Domain.Tests is referenced to MyProject.Domain.

In these projects I have classes with namespaces like project names.
So the strange thing happened when I can use public class from MyProject.Domain WITHOUT using MyProject.Domain.

Can anybody explain it ?

Comment: I think this is nothing new...  From `namespace A.B.C` you can reference classes defined in `namespace A.B`, or do I misunderstand your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're wondering why a type in the namespace `MyProject.Domain.Tests` can access types in the namespace `MyProject.Domain` without any `using`s. The reason for that is that the specification says so. From [Namespace and type names](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/basic-concepts.md#namespace-and-type-names) (edited by removing irrelevant parts):

> The meaning of a *namespace_or_type_name* is determined as follows:
>
> - If the *namespace_or_type_name* is of the form `I`:
>
>   - For each namespace `N`, starting with the namespace in which the *namespace_or_type_name*
>       occurs, **continuing with each enclosing namespace** (if any), and ending
>       with the global namespace, the following steps are evaluated until an
>       entity is located:
>
>     - If `N` contains an accessible type having name `I`, then:
>
>       - The *namespace_or_type_name* refers to the type.